# Issue with cell double-click

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

On reactJS ag-grid, I need to be able to edit a cell on double clicking. I tried the following code. I do not see any error message popping up. But the cell is still read-only.
Am I missing something here please?

Thanks.

```
function myTest(props)
{   
    const[gridApi, setGridApi] = userState(null);
...
...
    const onCellDoubleClicked = (params) =>
              {        
                gridApi.startEditingCell({rowIndex: params.node.id, colKey: "testField"}); 
            }
    
    const onGridReady = (params) =>
     {
      setGridApi(params.api);
     }
....
...
            {headerName:'Test', field:'testField', editable:false};
        
        <AgGridReact columnDefs={...} rowData={...} onCellDoubleClicked= 
        {onCellDoubleClicked} onGridReady={onGridReady}>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tough to say without seeing your coldef - I'd venture that you need to set the column(s) whose cells you want to be `editable` to true. See the docs below

[Cell Editing](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/cell-editing/)

Answer (score 1):

Add editable: true property in your column defs